# Android Time issue

Tags: java, android

```
 private void getSelectedTime(final String json){

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH); // Note: zero based!
        int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");


        JSONArray list;
        JSONObject jsonObject;

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

            list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("3");
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(list.get(0).toString(),"-");
            String startTime = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String endTime = tokenizer.nextToken();
            String temp1 = year+"/"+month+"/"+day+" "+startTime;
            String temp2 = year+"/"+month+"/"+day+" "+endTime;
            System.out.println("temp1="+temp1);
            System.out.println("temp2="+temp2);

            Date date1 = dateFormat.parse(temp1); // temp1=2012/5/25 03:00
            Date date2 = dateFormat.parse(temp2); //temp2=2012/5/25 03:06

            System.out.println("Year1="+date1.getYear());
            System.out.println("Month1="+date1.getMonth());
            System.out.println("Day1="+date1.getDay());
            System.out.println("Hour1="+date1.getHours());
            System.out.println("Minutes1="+date1.getMinutes());

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

In my application I am working with time and I have some issue here. Take a look below I have this result.

```
list.get(0) = 03:00-03:06
temp1=2012/5/25 03:00
temp2=2012/5/25 03:06
```

But when I am trying do this

```
System.out.println("Year="+date1.getYear());
System.out.println("Month="+date1.getMonth());
System.out.println("Day="+date1.getDay());
System.out.println("Hour="+date1.getHours());
System.out.println("Minutes="+date1.getMinutes());
```

I've got this result

```
Year=112
Month=4
Day=5
Hour=3
Minutes=0
```

Could anyone tell me why  the result is wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could anyone tell me why I the result is wrong?

Sure - you're using deprecated methods (you should be getting warnings - don't ignore them!), and you haven't read the docs for them. For example, from `Date.getYear()`:

> Returns a value that is the result of subtracting 1900 from the year that contains or begins with the instant in time represented by this Date object, as interpreted in the local time zone.

If you want to stick to the JDK, you should use `java.util.Calendar` instead (populating it with the `Date` via `setTime`) in an appropriate time zone. Note that months are still 0-based in `Calendar`, although the year is at least more sensible.

However, it would generally be better to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) if you possibly can. It's a much better thought-out API. It may be too large for you to want to use it on Android though - you may wish to see whether there's a cut-down version available.

Comment: @fish40: See my edited answer, or read the docs for the deprecation warnings.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do instead of `date1.getYear()`

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(date1);

int year = cal.get(Calendar.year);
```

This also works for other time values.
Or you can  use Joda Time that has been suggested already.